# camera is not changing in ios

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

Using AVFoundation, I'm stuck at a change camera from **rear to front** and **front to rear**.
For that I'm using following code.

```
- (IBAction)CameraToggleButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] count] > 1)        
    {
        NSError *error;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *NewVideoInput;
        AVCaptureDevicePosition position = [[VideoInputDevice device] position];
        if (position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
        {
            NewVideoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[self CameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront] error:&error];
        }
        else if (position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront)
        {
            NewVideoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[self CameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack] error:&error];
        }
        if (NewVideoInput != nil)
        {
            [CaptureSession beginConfiguration];                        [CaptureSession removeInput:VideoInputDevice];
            if ([CaptureSession canAddInput:NewVideoInput])
            {
                [CaptureSession addInput:NewVideoInput];
                VideoInputDevice = NewVideoInput;
            }
            else
            {
                [CaptureSession addInput:VideoInputDevice];
            }
            [self CameraSetOutputProperties];
            [CaptureSession commitConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

`[CaptureSession canAddInput:NewVideoInput]` returns always false, so camera is not going to change. 
I'm not getting any point why session can not add new input device.
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to remove previous Input before adding new one. Check here

Comment: @stefos, then what will be effect of the statement I wrote in code `[CaptureSession removeInput:VideoInputDevice];`

Answer (score 0):

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer;
bool isUsingFrontFacingCamera;
```

Method:

```
- (void) switchCam{

    if (![self cameraIsRunning])
        return;

    AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition;

    if (isUsingFrontFacingCamera)
        desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    else
        desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;

    for (AVCaptureDevice *d in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {

        if ([d position] == desiredPosition) {

            [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] beginConfiguration];

            AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:d error:nil];

            for (AVCaptureInput *oldInput in [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] inputs]) {
                [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] removeInput:oldInput];
            }

            [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] addInput:input];
            [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] commitConfiguration];

            break;
        }
    }

    isUsingFrontFacingCamera = !isUsingFrontFacingCamera;
}

- (bool) cameraIsRunning{

    return [session isRunning];
}
```

Comment: removing all inputDevice from session is not making any difference. I already tested before posting here.